# Create trigger that delete data from table at specific time

Tags: sql, oracle

I am very new in Oracle SQL Trigger concept . Help me out , I am welling to write a Trigger concept which will Trigger the script on ever 31 December at 12:01 AM and delete the data from Table.

Also help me out whether it correct to write Trigger concept or not .

Comment: Sounds to me like you need a scheduled job  https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28310/scheduse.htm

Comment: it should be job task not trigger. see documentation about `DBMS_SCHEDULER` and `dbms_job`

Comment: i think you have to create a procedure or function not a trigger and job for scheduling, trigger executes when there's a manipulation on the data, so you cannot schedule it